# How to cancel Android Studio build?

Tags: android-studio

After I initiated the build or assemble process I can't effectively cancel it if I suddenly need to do something.

If I click the red cross the process will be renamed to **"Stopping build..."** but ultimately will continue until it finishes. The only way I can effectively stop it is to shut down `AS`.
Is it a IDE bug of am I doing something wrong? (besides double checking every time I press build ofc)

Comment: It will take some time to stop building gradle. Try disconnecting your PC from internet connection. It might help a bit. If you want your project build to boost up go to -> Settings -> Search Global Gradle Settings -> Choose Gradle under Build, Execution, Deployment option and check "Offline work"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Android Studio by default uses Gradle to build/assemble. So when you click the *build* button in the IDE, a Gradle daemon is started and performs the task.

[The Gradle userguide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#N1046E) states:

> **6.2. Stopping an existing Daemon**
>
> As mentioned, the Daemon is a background process. You needn’t worry
>   about a build up of Gradle processes on your machine, though: every
>   Daemon stops after 3 hours of inactivity. If you want to explicitly
>   stop a Daemon process for any reason, just use the command gradle
>   --stop.
>
> This will terminate all Daemon processes that were started with the
>   same version of Gradle used to execute the command. If you have the
>   Java Development Kit (JDK) installed, you can easily verify that a
>   Daemon has stopped by running the jps command. You’ll see any running
>   Daemons listed with the name GradleDaemon.

So depending on your project configuration you could either call `gradlew --stop` or use your specified gradle executable with `--stop`. However, I am not sure if that isn't exactly what Android Studio does internally, when you click the button with the red cross. Probably the `--stop` terminates the daemon only after the task was executed. In that case, there is most likely no way to kill the process.

Comment: Thank you! Running "gradlew --stop" in the terminal effectively kills ongoing process

Comment: This didn't work for me on a mac, I had to force kill java using Activity Monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Gradle once started building cannot be stopped.
It will ultimately build and then reject to nothingness.
So its useless to stop build... :(